# Passing fstrings as parameters in Python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, file-writing

I'm trying to write to a csv file and to do so I have to pass some values stored in different variables to the writerow method. But when I try to do so i always get this error:

> 'SyntaxError: closing parenthesis ')' does not match opening parenthesis '{''.

I've already tried using the old fashion method of "%s" but the error remains the same. Here is my code trying to implement the f string method:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

specialists = {'ST', 'LS', 'KR', 'PR', 'K', 'P'}

AFC_North = [0, {'CIN', 'BAL', 'CLE', 'PIT'}, 'AFC North']
AFC_East = [0, {'NWE', 'BUF', 'MIA', 'NYJ'}, 'AFC East']
AFC_West = [0, {'KAN', 'LAC', 'DEN', 'LVR'}, 'AFC West']
AFC_South = [0, {'HOU', 'JAX', 'TEN', 'IND'}, 'AFC South']

NFC_North = [0, {'GNB', 'MIN', 'DET', 'CHI'}, 'NFC North']
NFC_East = [0, {'PHI', 'DAL', 'WAS', 'NYG'}, 'NFC East']
NFC_West = [0, {'LAR', 'ARI', 'SEA', 'SFO'}, 'NFC West']
NFC_South = [0, {'TAM', 'NOR', 'CAR', 'ATL'}, 'NFC South']

AFC = [AFC_North, AFC_East, AFC_West, AFC_South]
NFC = [NFC_North, NFC_East, NFC_West, NFC_South]

## Writting
with open("All-Pros_1970-2022", 'w', newline="") as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Div', 'Yr', 'AP']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

def wdraft(draft_year):    
    with open(f'csvs/AP{draft_year}.csv', 'r+') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        
        for row in csv_reader:
            if 'AP: 1st Tm' in row['All-pro teams'] or 'AP: 2nd Tm' in row['All-pro teams'] and row['Pos'] not in specialists:
    
                for i in range(len(AFC)):
                    if row['Tm'] in AFC[i][1]:
                        AFC[i][0] += 1
                    elif row['Tm'] in NFC[i][1]:
                        NFC[i][0] += 1                        
                    ## Handling two teams in a season case
                if '2TM' in row['Tm']:
                    print(row['Player'])
                    exc = int(input("Where do you want to put him?\n 0-8 (AFC-NFC, N,E,W,S)"))
                    if exc == 0:
                        AFC_North[0] +=1
                    elif exc == 1:
                        AFC_East[0] +=1
                    elif exc == 2:
                        AFC_West[0] +=1
                    elif exc == 3:
                        AFC_South[0] +=1
                    elif exc == 4:
                        NFC_North[0] +=1
                    elif exc == 5:
                        NFC_East[0] +=1
                    elif exc == 6:
                        NFC_West[0] +=1
                    elif exc == 7:
                        NFC_South[0] +=1
                        
        for i in AFC:
            row = {
                'Div': f"{ i[2] }",
                'Yr': f"{ draft_year }",
                'AP': f"{ i[0] }"
            }
            writer.writerow(row)
        for i in NFC:
            row = {
                'Div': f"{ i[2] }",
                'Yr': f"{ draft_year }",
                'AP': f"{ i[0] }"
            }
            writer.writerow(row)
                             
        return f'{draft_year} was succesfully loaded'
print(wdraft(2022))
```

Is there any way to pass an f string or smth similar as an argument? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your dictionary parameter is not closed thus the closing `)` is unexpected.

Comment: I also strongly suspect you don't want to write the default string format of you dictionary as that will result in invalid JSON. You probably want to look at `json.dumps()` applied to your dictionary.

Comment: @JonSG I've already fixed the mistake related to the not closed dict. And as you said, when i run it returned an error 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.' But I'm writting a csv file not a json, does it change what you just said?

Comment: we will need to see more of your code, specifically how you define `writer` in the context of the file you used with `open()`. Please update your question to reflect your current issue or open a new question :-)

Comment: @JonSG Thanks for helping man, I've expanded the code shown in order to demonstrate the writer definition

Answer (score 0):

The core issue you have is that the function you define is the middle of your for loop is kind of messing things up. Let's move it out of the for loop, clean it up a bit and let it do just the data loading. Once the data is loaded, we can then write it out.

Note this is untested as I don't know what your input data looks like:

```py
import csv

def wdraft(draft_year):    
    with open(f'csvs/AP{draft_year}.csv', 'r+') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            criteria = 'AP: 1st Tm' in row['All-pro teams'] or 'AP: 2nd Tm' in row['All-pro teams'] and row['Pos'] not in specialists
            if not criteria:
                continue

            ## ----------------------
            ## Increment a value in the given league/region data
            ## ----------------------
            for region in AFC:
                if row['Tm'] in region[1]:
                    region[0] += 1
                    break
            else:
                for region in NFC:
                    if row['Tm'] in region[1]:
                        region[0] += 1
                        break
            ## ----------------------

            if not '2TM' in row['Tm']:
                continue

            ## ----------------------
            ## Handling two teams in a season case
            ## ----------------------
            print(row['Player'])
            exc = int(input("Where do you want to put him?\n 0-8 (AFC-NFC, N,E,W,S)"))
            (AFC + NFC)[exc] += 1
            ## ----------------------

specialists = {'ST', 'LS', 'KR', 'PR', 'K', 'P'}

AFC_North = [0, {'CIN', 'BAL', 'CLE', 'PIT'}, 'AFC North']
AFC_East = [0, {'NWE', 'BUF', 'MIA', 'NYJ'}, 'AFC East']
AFC_West = [0, {'KAN', 'LAC', 'DEN', 'LVR'}, 'AFC West']
AFC_South = [0, {'HOU', 'JAX', 'TEN', 'IND'}, 'AFC South']

NFC_North = [0, {'GNB', 'MIN', 'DET', 'CHI'}, 'NFC North']
NFC_East = [0, {'PHI', 'DAL', 'WAS', 'NYG'}, 'NFC East']
NFC_West = [0, {'LAR', 'ARI', 'SEA', 'SFO'}, 'NFC West']
NFC_South = [0, {'TAM', 'NOR', 'CAR', 'ATL'}, 'NFC South']

AFC = [AFC_North, AFC_East, AFC_West, AFC_South]
NFC = [NFC_North, NFC_East, NFC_West, NFC_South]

DRAFT_YEAR = 2022

wdraft(DRAFT_YEAR)
print(f'{DRAFT_YEAR} was loaded')

## ----------------------
## Writting
## ----------------------
with open("All-Pros_1970-2022", 'w', newline="") as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Div', 'Yr', 'AP']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for div in (AFC+NFC):
        writer.writerow({
            'Div': f"{ div[2] }",
            'Yr': f"{ DRAFT_YEAR }",
            'AP': f"{ div[0] }"            
        })
## ----------------------
```

Comment: it still outputs the same error :(. I updated the original post in order to show my whole code in case I broke it somwhere else. The handling of the 'two teams in one season' looks awful, sorry for your eyes

Comment: I've just got home that's why i couldn't write before. I've tried the code and there was just a little problem handling the two teams in a season case. but nvm i've just fixed it. I want to thank you very much for the help. this is my first project related with data analysis and I was a little confused. but i could look up to you to realize what things i could have improved and realize them, it helped me to progress a lot. again, thanks for helping, i appreciate it a lot